# Decode Base64 within Spark Dataframe using Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hbase, decode

I've a hbase table which gets a base64 value for one of it's column.
I want to decode the same value within spark dataframe into ASCII and replace that value with the earlier encoded value of the column in the dataframe.
How can this be achieved ?

Answer (score 1):

Import and use the below code

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.unbase64
val resultDF = inputDF.withColumn("newColName", unbase64(inputDF.colNameofBase64))
```

Comment: Hello @Taha Naqvi, I'm getting below error after importing and executing the statement given by you. Error : value P_RAWVALUE is not a member of org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame. My statement is : df.withColumn('newColname',unbase64(df.P_RAWVALUE)) What mistake am I doing ?

Comment: df.withColumn('newColname',unbase64(col("P_RAWVALUE"))

Comment: Hello Taha,
I tried the statement given by you:
It gives the below error:
df.withColumn('newColname',unbase64(col("P_RAWVALUE"))
<console>:1: error: unclosed character literal
df.withColumn('newColname',unbase64(col("P_RAWVALUE"))

Comment: df.withColumn("new",unbase64(col("P_RAWVALUE")))
Last bracket was missing.